# java getting list from other class

Tags: java, android, list, class, arraylist

Hello android and java experts, it sounds simple: I have a list "getOnlyNearGeofences" in class "HauptActivity". I want to access this list in another class "MainActivity". For this I created a method in "HauptActivity" :

```
public List<Double> getOnlyNearGeofences(){
        return onlyNearGeofences;
    }
```

In "MainActivity" I initialize the class and then I want to access the method in onCreate-method:

```
HauptActivity hauptActivity = new HauptActivity();

...

hauptActivity.getOnlyNearGeofences().get(1) // get list from other class and take value at index 1
```

My app crashes when I execute the code. With other attributes (just double, string or integer) it works but not with the list. Is there a special thing with arraylists?

Comment: `HauptActivity hauptActivity = new HauptActivity();` you should never ever create an instance of an activity like this

Comment: didnt know. But why not?

Comment: activities should be scheduled by the OS, you can't just create an instance of them like this. with all due respect, your question seems like you could easily solve it yourself by just searching how to pass an array of data between activities

Comment: Silly question - but are you sure there is anything in "onlyNearGeofences"?  If it is null or empty you'll get a `NullPointerException` or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception respectively...

Comment: It is not null, I tried it out.

Comment: Many bad practices in your code. I suggest you check good practices in Android and possibly implement a clean architecture that will directly solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

So, based on the comments I found out that you need an intent for that. For everyone who will land on this page in future, just look at: https://aatul.me/tag/passing-array-between-activities-in-android-using-intent-and-bundle/ . There are also many other sites that show you the solution.

Comment: He doesn't want to copy the list, he wants to access that same list. Also post a part of the solution here, simply linking to external sites is not a good answer.

Comment: It is me, who asked. I want to access, thats right. But when I copy the list to the other class I can work with that and access it too, or not?

Comment: Depends if the list is going to change and you need to reflect those changes as well.